# civicrm wordpress installation fails with: You have requested a non-existent service "spec_gatherer"

Tags: wordpress, installation, php

I'm trying to install Civicrm on Wordpress within this docker setup: https://lab.3sd.io/tools/civicrm-docker/

I tried the `michaelmcandrew/civicrm:5.59.2-wordpress-php8.1` and `civicrm:5.56.0-wordpress-php7.4` image. When it comes to the actual installation step it fails with:

```
...
[14-Mar-2023 15:22:36 UTC] MixinLoader: Failed to load "setting-php@1.0.0" for extension "sequentialcreditnotes"
 
In ContainerBuilder.php line 1030:
 
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
  You have requested a non-existent service "spec_gatherer".
...
```

Find the full trace here: https://pastebin.com/gyznjbjY

To get this far I already had to make some adjustments to the configs, this is the actual configuration I use: https://git.coopcloud.tech/yksflip/civicrm/src/branch/main/civicrm.settings.php

I have almost no php experience, so I'm happy about any hint!

Bests,
yksflip